# WebView2 NavigationCompleted gets WebErrorStatus=ConnectionAborted

Tags: c#, webview, webview2

```
private async void NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_webViewDisposed > 0)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("NavigationCompleted : WebViewDisposed");
        OnWebViewFailure();
        return;
    }

    if (!e.IsSuccess)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"NavigationCompleted: {e.WebErrorStatus}");
        OnWebViewFailure();
        return;
    }
```

Here `NavigationCompleted` gets `WebErrorStatus=ConnectionAborted`

In the constructor I have `WebView.NavigationCompleted += NavigationCompleted;`

And on some other place I have `WebView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(_viewModel.Content);`
The content is valid HTML.

I have also successfuly initialzed Webview object here:

```
 await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(WebViewHelper.Instance);

 _logger.LogInfo($"Version: {WebView.CoreWebView2.Environment?.BrowserVersionString}, UserDataFolder: {WebView.CoreWebView2.Environment?.UserDataFolder}.");

 await _baseWebViewMessageHandler.InjectScript();
```

It just fails sometimes. Can you hint what could be reason of `WebErrorStatus=ConnectionAborted`?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `WebView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(_viewModel.Content)` was called twice on the same time.

I solve with this:

```
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _navigateWebViewToContent) == 1)
    {
        WebView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(_viewModel.Content);
    }
```

Comment: I think you should find out, why the code is called twice, might indicate an error is your program logic.

Comment: That was classic race condition case. My code waits for two events: WebView initialization and Content download. If it gets one it checks if other is available and calles NavigateToString if bot are available. Sometimes two events occur on the same time.